# Magento 2 Theme installation using filezilla

Tags: magento, magento2, filezilla

I am new to Magento. I have downloaded a theme to install on Magento. I am using filezilla client. When I upload the theme files that is app,js,lib,media and skin using filezilla, I get failed transfers. All the files are not getting transferred. Why?

Comment: Is filezilla giving you any kind of error message?

Comment: It just gives a message saying this amount of files could not be transferred.

Comment: There may be permission issue please check.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?